# i want to fetch all text from a text file and convert in to a xml file

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

This is the format of my text file i want to fetch Text and headline specifically so please suggest me how to do it. Now i'm trying to first convert this text to a dataset but can't getting success to fetch Text node value in this text.

```
BoxID{26027836}
Left{8.346457}
Top{14.296841}
Bottom{20.563504}
Right{12.952756}
Text{8.346457,14.819063,20.563504,12.952737 Tika R Pradhan

Kathmandu, January 24

The central committee of the UCPN-Maoist has told party Chairman Pushpa Kamal Dahal to present his proposal for the revival of the party.

According to senior leader Haribol Gajurel, 98 CC members have already aired their views at the ongoing CC meeting demanding a new lease of life for the party.  The CC decided to resume its meeting on Tuesday, giving the party chief the time to present a proposal on party restructuring. The hiatus also takes into account the Legislature-Parliament meeting slated for Monday. 

Gajurel said discussions on fresh issues will begin after chairman presents his plan on Tuesday. 

He said Dahal will float his plan for party restructuring, adding that the plan will also cover ethics that the party’s rank and file should adhere to. 

The CC meeting that kicked off eight days ago dwelt on the political document that Dahal had presented. The document has raised questions without bothering to offer solutions. 

During today’s meeting, party leader Renu Chand pointed that people have made negative comments about Chairman’s son Prakash Dahal. She urged Dahal to remove his son from his secretariat. Krishna Dhital, a party leader from Gorkha, asked party leader Narayan Kaji Shrestha to explain why he appointed a lady personal secretary. 
  EOF9.000000}
Text{10.038215,15.732951,19.470202,12.834632 Himalayan News Service 

Kathmandu, January 24

UCPN-Maoist leaders have started discussions on selection of the party’s parliamentary party leader. 

With former vice-chairman Baburam announcing that he does not want to hold any political position for at least a year, party Chairman Pushpa Kamal Dahal is under pressure not to stake his claim on the position. Sources claimed Dahal will support his close confidante Krishna Bahadur Mahara for the position. 

Since Bhattarai is against Mahara, he will field his close aide Top Bahadur Rayamajhi for the position. Another former vice-chairman Narayan Kaji Shrestha will back Giriraj Mani Pokhrel. 

Some leaders close to Dahal claim that Dahal himself may take up the responsibility of the PP leader if subordinates start quarrelling for the position. Others say the party will settle the issue by making Mahara the PP leader, Rayamajhi deputy leader and Pokhrel the chief whip of the PP. 

Senior leader Shrestha, however, said top leaders have not yet discussed the selection of the PP leader. He said the meeting of the central office, which will begin tomorrow, will begin discussions on the issue. He said all options, including Dahal and Mahara’s PP leadership, are open for discussion. 
  EOF8.500000}
Headline{10.038215,15.013414,15.851079,12.834632 Parliamentary Party leadership in focus  EOF27.000000}
Headline{8.346457,14.296841,14.819063,12.952738 UCPN-M revival plan sought  EOF38.000000}

BoxID{25861210}
Left{11.161417}
Top{5.569194}
Bottom{5.680180}
Right{12.952756}
Text{11.161417,5.569194,5.680180,12.952756 THT
  EOF5.000000}

BoxID{26027216}
Left{8.346287}
Top{8.552401}
Bottom{14.166286}
Right{10.314763}
Headline{8.346287,8.552401,9.727400,10.314763 TB patients jeopardising their own lives   EOF29.000000}
Text{8.346287,9.727400,14.166286,10.314763 Himalayan News Service

Dipayal, January 24

TB patients in Doti district have been playing with their own lives by not adhering to the Directly Observed Treatment Shortcourse, an intensive treatment method against tuberculosis. 

For eight months, medical personnel administer doses to TB patients and perform health checkups. But this method is proving ineffective in treating the respiratory disease with the patients not bothering to visit designated centres for prescribed doses, says focal person and District Public Health Officer, Bhim Prasad Paudel. “We remind patients to take medicine on time, but they pay no heed,” he says. Forty per cent of around 300 patients on DOTS have not been abiding by the rules. Paudel blames it on the lack of adequate knowledge among patients about DOTS and adverse consequences that result from non-adherence to the medication schedule. 

DPHO Chief Mahendradhwaj Adhikari says only a handful of patients approach designated hospitals for treatment regularly. “In many cases, they come only at the last stage,” he observes. 
  EOF9.000000}
```

Comment: Can anyone suggest me what to do with this, it's important pls reply me fast..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like the following should achieve what you're looking for. The solution I'm providing here will transform all the data in your source text to XML. You will probably need to modify what I've provided to meet your requirements more specifically, but the following should give you a good start.

```
string fileContents = File.ReadAllText("input.txt"); //your example source text is in this file
string pattern = @"(.*)?\{([^}]+)\}";

MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(fileContents, pattern, RegexOptions.Multiline);

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.AppendLine("<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>");
sb.AppendLine("<contents>");

foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    string nodeName = match.Groups[1].Value;
    string nodeValue = match.Groups[2].Value;

    sb.AppendFormat("<{0}>{1}</{0}>", nodeName.ToLower(), nodeValue);
    sb.AppendLine();
}
sb.AppendLine("</contents>");

File.WriteAllText("output.xml", sb.ToString());
```

The "input.txt" file contains your source text. I'm using a StringBuilder to create the XML string before dumping to a file, for the purposes of this example. Obviously, if you need to work with the XML immediately after transformation, you'd want to use XDocument (or XMLDocument, depending on the version of .Net you're using). StringBuilder is simply faster than XDocument / XMLDocument so that's why I'm using it to create the output XML file.

Comment: thanks Lawrence but the string builder doesn't work for this so i'm using XmlDocument for writing the text in to xml file.

Comment: I need to add one more node from BoxId to Next BoxId like in Contents node there are multiple subnodes of content